# Azure Cosmos DB NoSQL Exclude all property paths but keeping indexing active

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to create a container in which the only property that should be indexed is the /id property.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#includeexclude-strategy) states:

> If the indexing mode is set to consistent, the system properties id
> and _ts are automatically indexed.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv3%2Cpythonv3#exclude-all-property-paths-but-keeping-indexing-active) also states:

> You can use this policy where the Time-to-Live (TTL) feature is active
> but no other indexes are necessary to use Azure Cosmos DB as a pure
> key-value store

... and shows the following indexing policy:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "includedPaths": [],
    "excludedPaths": [{
        "path": "/*"
    }]
}
```

I am using the following C# code to set the indexing policy on a container **at the time the container is created**:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties container_props;

Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.IndexingPolicy indexing_policy;


// Set container properties ...

container_props = new();

container_props.Id = "mycontainer";

container_props.PartitionKeyPath = "/id";


// Set indexing policy ...

indexing_policy = new IndexingPolicy();

indexing_policy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;

indexing_policy.IncludedPaths.Add( new IncludedPath { Path = "[]" } );

indexing_policy.ExcludedPaths.Add( new ExcludedPath { Path = "\"/*\"" } );

container_props.IndexingPolicy = indexing_policy;


// Check if container exists, and if not create it ...

await db.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync( container_props );
```

When the code is executed the following exception is raised:

```
Unable to initialize container: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: ba5a76a0-e4ee-4aa5-9dd8-1e2bf8313c84; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["The indexing path '[]' could not be accepted, failed near position '0'. Please ensure that the path is a valid path. Common errors include invalid characters or absence of quotes around labels."]}
```

I have also tried using:

```
indexing_policy.IncludedPaths.Add( new IncludedPath { Path = "\"[]\"" } );
```

... which also results in the following exception:

```
Unable to initialize container: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 5dfe0a6a-7b76-4955-9bf5-f4f248cfc115; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["The indexing path '\"[]\"' could not be accepted, failed near position '0'. Please ensure that the path is a valid path. Common errors include invalid characters or absence of quotes around labels."]}
```

Clearly, I am doing something wrong with regard to encoding the path.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties container_props;

Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.IndexingPolicy indexing_policy;


// Set container properties ...

container_props = new();

container_props.Id = "mycontainer";

container_props.PartitionKeyPath = "/id";


// Set indexing policy ...

indexing_policy = new IndexingPolicy();

indexing_policy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;

indexing_policy.IncludedPaths.Clear();

indexing_policy.ExcludedPaths.Clear();

indexing_policy.ExcludedPaths.Add( new ExcludedPath { Path = "/*" } );

container_props.IndexingPolicy = indexing_policy;


// Check if container exists, and if not create it ...

await db.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync( container_props );
```

When executed, the indexing policy on the container shows as follows:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

... not sure why the _etag path is present (seems Azure is adding this path regardless).

I was incorrectly assuming the "[]" was a JSON path, but the "includePaths" and "excludePaths" properties are collections of JSON paths - so the JSON "[]" shown in the examples means an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

`indexing_policy.IncludedPaths` is already an empty collection. You don't need to add anything to that. When it is serialized into a json the value of `IncludedPaths` will be translated to `[]`.

So simply remove the next line:

```cs
indexing_policy.IncludedPaths.Add( new IncludedPath { Path = "[]" } );
```

Comment: Yes - I just figured that out and posted an answer -- thanks for taking the time.